# jQuery: What are { and } used for?

Tags: javascript

I am experimenting with jQuery plugins and I noticed a segment of code similar to the one below on: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

```
var defaults = {
    value : 'hello, world'
}

var options = $.extend(defaults,options)
```

My question is: What are { and }? Are they like arrays? How can I get the value of 'value'?

Comment: -1 as this question does not show any research effort. Please refer to the [JavaScript Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript) or [JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide) for basic JavaScript overviews and explanations of the language.

Comment: That's why beginners shouldn't start learning javascript with jQuery..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{}` are for defining objects, see: [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

```
var person = {
  name: 'john',
  age: 43
}
```

means the same as

```
var person = new Object()
person.name = 'john';
person.age = 43;
```

In your code a simple object is created and passed to the jquery `extend()` function

Comment: [W3Fools – A W3Schools Intervention](http://w3fools.com/). +1 for linking now to the mozilla docs. Nice section in there on `Using object initializers`.

Comment: XD W3Fools... I'll give you guys my plugin sense you helped me out so quickly!

Answer (score 4):

In your code, `{}` is an object literal. It's an object-oriented way to contain data. [Learn more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers).

In short, object literals store heterogeneous lists of key-value pairs. For example:

```
var x = { key : value }
```

Don't be confused with what you see here and with this:

```
var x = function() { .. }
```

The brackets here denote a block that contains the execution environment of the function. This is **not** the same as an object literal as functions are meant to run code in a controlled environment while object literals are containers for data. [Learn more about functions here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

To answer your question: To get the value of `value` we must first list the object on which it was created, followed by a dot `.` and lastly the property `value`. Like this:

```
defaults.value; // 'hello, world'
```

If you run this in the console (`console.log`) you will see that string.

Note that this construct isn't specific to jQuery but to JavaScript itself. jQuery is a library made out of JS and therefore abides by the same syntactical rules JS possess.

Answer (score 1):

The `{` and `}` (curly braces) are used for to create object literals.  `value` is an *attribute* or *member* of `defaults`.

Objects are ways to store multiple pieces of data as a single unit, and often include other operations and actions that can be performed by it.  They provide an often intuitive way to model things in the real world using code.

If you want to access the string stored in `value`, call `defaults.value`.

Answer (score 0):

They are Hashes (or to be strict, Associative arrays), to get the value of "Value", you can do:

```
   defaults['value'];
```

Alternately:

```
   defaults.value;
```

to check if an associative Array has a key "value" you can do:

```
  defaults.hasOwnProperty('value');
```

and to add a string with key 'value':

```
  defaults['value'] = 'some string';
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your fast responses! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects Helped out a lot as well!

Comment: `defaults.value` works fine all the way back to IE4. `value` is not a reserved word.